# Adding a javascript file to Angular7 dist folder

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications

I'm building an app in Angular7 and it's ready to go but I need to create a plain javascript (hopefully could be minified) to be included in the websites which are going to use the main Angular app. This script will embed the app into an iframe when users click buttons or links. What I want is to have that script and the Angular app as part of the same bundle but not included as part of the angular app. Just available to control what the host website can do to embed our main app. If there is another approach to solve this problem I will appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Create custom js file

```
exports.myFunction = function myFunction() {
    alert('External custom js');
}
```

Add this JavaScript file in scripts array in angular.json file.

```
"scripts": [
  .....
  "src/assets/js/custom.js"
]
```

If in your js file have function myFunction you can declare in the component

```
import {myFunction} from '../assets/js/custom.js';
```

I make a demo for custom.js

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-js?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: yes but that is including the file in the index.html. How can I do exactly the same this is doing but not being included in the index.html? thanks

Comment: no need add in index.html, you can use in component

Comment: I mean that when you add this scripts to the angular.json the compiler will add the <script> tag to your index.html

Comment: do you want use custom js in index.html?

Comment: What I want is to have a 'vanilla javascript' file but not included in the index.html because I want to use that file from any other website which wants to use my main angular app, but this script will do just a little task: open the anular app in an iframe

Comment: You should not include in index.html, you should use in component ts